# Reset Password in symfony usnig mailer

Tags: symfony, mailer, reset-password

I have installed mailer and changed the DSN_Mailer in .env , i have no errors in the page and the reset password request is saved in the database but the email doesnt receive any email for the reset link ...

Comment: you provide very very little actual information. have you run `bin/console mailer:test [email] -vvv` to at least check if the mailer is configured properly? because to be honest, your question is very unspecific in what actually happens on your system. It's somewhat clear on what you're doing, but from what you've shown us so far, there is no indication that you have tried to debug this yourself...